# slope-unstable sheaves under restriction

Tags: complex-geometry

In the book "Geometry of Higher Dimensional Algebraic Varieties" of Peternell it says: Let $H$ be a very ample divisor in a variety $X$ of dimension $\geq2$ and $Y \in |H| $ a generic member. It is easy to see that, if $E$ is an $H$-unstable sheaf then $E \mid_Y$ is an $H\mid_Y$-unstable sheaf. 
How do you prove this?

I tried the following:
If $E$ is $H$-unstable, then there exists a maximal destabilizer $E_1 \subsetneq E$. The maximal destabilizer $E_1$ of a torsion free sheaf $E$ is saturated because of its maximality. Therefore the quotient $E/E_1$ is torsion free and you can check that $\mu_{max}(E/E_1) < \mu_{max}(E) $. How can I show that the restrictions to the generic divisor $E \mid_Y$ and $E_1 \mid_Y$ are still torsion free and that $(E/E_1) \mid_Y$ is still a destabilizing quotient of $E \mid_Y$?

Comment: With your notations, you have $\mu(E_1)=\mu((E_1)|_{Y})$ and same for $E$ and $E|_{Y}$ as $Y\in |H|$. Therefore if $E_1$ destabilizes $E$, then $(E_1)|_Y$ destabilizes $E|_{Y}$ as well. Moreover, the restriction of a torsion free sheaf to a generic subvariety is always torsion free.